# Flutter Build For Android and IOS Issue

Tags: build, flutter, apk, cross-platform, ipa

I'm having a hard time to find how to build the .apk and .ipa on Flutter.

I'm using Android Studio to make the apps, but I have no ideia on how to build it and I can't find any tutorial or documentation showing how to do it. I need to know how viable is it, because I pretend to create a lot of apps and grow on Flutter developing, so I need to know how to build and deploy my apps.

I'm just starting at Flutter developing, so I'm very beginner.
I'm using windows, can I build and deploy my apps, both for Android and IOS on it?

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51000869/flutter-how-to-make-release-version-in-android-studio

Comment: For [Android](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android), for [iOS](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/ios)

Comment: All right, but I still don't have Xcode, since I'm running for windows, and the links doesn't teach me how to build both APK and an IPA files and use them as I want.

I don't know if it's actually possible to do what I'm thinking, since I'm new to Flutter and mobile developing, I don't know if that's how it works.

Is it possible to build and take both files or not?

Is it possible to build ipa files on Android Studio, or I need to have a MacBook?